# TensorFlow to Core ML Convertor Throwing Errors

Tags: tensorflow

I am using TensorFlow to Core ML convertor to convert a TensorFlow model to Core ML. I keep getting assertion errors as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use with keras

```
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert('./Any.h5',
                                            input_names='image',
                                            image_input_names='image',
                                            output_names='output',
                                            class_labels=['1', '2'],
                                            image_scale=1/255)
coreml_model.save('abc.mlmodel')
```

.h5 can easily created by 'Sequential'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tf_converter.convert(tf_model_path = 'inception_v1_2016_08_28_frozen.pb',
                     mlmodel_path = 'InceptionV1.mlmodel',
                     output_feature_names = ['InceptionV1/Logits/Predictions/Softmax:0'])
```

You need to run `tf-coreml/utils/inspect_pb.py` to get a summary of all the nodes to get the correct name of the output node. In this case it is `InceptionV1/Logits/Predictions/Softmax:0`